# Extract friends Id's from long sting in r

Tags: r, regex, substring, extract

I have a data frame with thousand rows. Data frame contain many columns, where 3rd column contains a long string in each cell, shown as below.

```
> file_analysis$parameters[1]
[1] {"friends_id": [8396105, 20289687, 8222966], "opp_groups": [], "group_count": 752, "likes_count": 0, "friends_count": 3}
> file_analysis$parameters[2]
[1] {"friends_id": [7874795, 8093749], "opp_groups": [], "group_count": 69, "likes_count": 0, "posts_count": 0, "friends_count": 2}
> file_analysis$parameters[3]
[1] {"friends_id": [], "opp_groups": [], "group_count": 292, "likes_count": 0, "posts_count": 0, "friends_count": 0}
```

In few columns, friends Id's does not exist. But, in few columns, there are more than 1 friends Id's exist. As you can see the above 3 cells, there are following friends Id's.

```
"friends_id": [8396105, 20289687, 8222966]
"friends_id": [7874795, 8093749]
"friends_id": []
```

I want to extract these id's from each cell in separate column. 
In every iteration, I want a vector of friends Id's. Further, I want to check, weather vector is empty or not.

The output I want is follows;

```
id1 = (8396105, 20289687, 8222966)
id2 = (7874795, 8093749)
id2 = NULL
```

Comment: Post parts of your data using `dput(data)` or if it's a large dataset `dput(head(data))`

Comment: File contains too much large data.

Comment: I have found the solution, but not complete. kindly see the Answer bellow. How can I further make a vector of these Ids?

Comment: You have an object called file_analysis.  You can post the data using 'dput(head(file_analysis)'.

Comment: Thank you dear, I have found the exact solution what I want. Find the ans below.

Answer (score 0):

First, Install the library.

```
library(qdapRegex)
```

Then, run the following line.

```
> x = rm_between(file_analysis$parameters[1], "\": [", "]", extract=TRUE)[[1]][1]
  x
 [1] "8396105, 20289687, 8222966"
```

Now, further make a vector of above string.

```
 y = unlist(strsplit(x, split=", "))
```